# how to modify my table?

Tags: tables

I would like to change the formatting of the table I wrote, making it similar to the table shown in the figure. thanks a lot to everyone. Could you help me? thanks a lot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5}                    
\frenchspacing 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}

   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
   %\usepackage{mathpple}
   %\usepackage{palatino}
   \usepackage{lxfonts}
%   
%   \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{pifont}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{bbding}
 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }
 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
   \fbox{%
     \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
       \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
       #2
     }%
   }%
   \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
%  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \toprule
    $ c $       & \begin{flushleft}
     $ y = 2\cdot a+1 $ \end{flushleft}  \\
    \midrule
    $ 0 $       &  $ 2\cdot \left( \ldots\ldots \right)+1  = \ldots\ldots =\ldots$ \\
    $ +1 $       & $ 2\cdot \left( \ldots\ldots \right)+1  = \ldots\ldots =\ldots$  \\
    $ +2 $       &    $ 2\cdot \left( \ldots\ldots \right)+1  = \ldots\ldots =\ldots$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to align the =

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|*{3}{>{$}l<{$}@{\,$=$\,}}>{$}l<{$}}
 a  & y                    & \multicolumn{1}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{}}{2\cdot a+1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{}     \\\hline
 0  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2\cdot(0)+1                                  & \ldots          & \ldots \\\hline
 +1 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2\cdot(+1)+1                                 & \ldots          & \ldots \\\hline
 +2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2\cdot(+2)+1                                 & \ldots          & \ldots \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a left aligned column (by using `l` instead of `c`).  I've also removed `\left`and `\right` because they have no effect here.  Also I think one `\ldots` is enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|l}
  \toprule
  $ c $  & $ y = 2\cdot a+1 $                     \\
  \midrule
  $ 0 $  & $ 2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  $ +1 $ & $ 2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  $ +2 $ & $ 2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get it like in the picture, use `arydshln`.  And increase `\arraystretch` a little.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
  $c$  & $y = 2\cdot a+1$                      \\
  \hline
  $0$  & $2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  \hdashline
  $+1$ & $2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  \hdashline
  $+2$ & $2\cdot(\ldots)+1  = \ldots = \ldots$ \\
  \hdashline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would right-align the first column (or use `\phantom{+}0`) to align the numerals.

Comment: that's great! thank you very much! I'll try \phantom{+}0 ;)